# Gmail multiple attachments select in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, gmail, attachments

Somehow, I can't use the usual "Ctrl" or "Shift" key to select multiple attachments using Gmail on Ubuntu Linux (browser - Google chrome).

Apparently, its allowed: http://digitizor.com/2009/02/26/Gmail-adds-progress-bar-and-multiple-select-for-attachment-uploads/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that does not work, at least in Gnome, but you can open a separate file manager and drag multiple files to attachment pane.